# ActiveCell.Offset Confusion

Tags: vba, excel

I was reading some VBA in a previous module somebody had written and came across something that confused me:

```
Sheets("Setup").Select
Range("Start").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

I was wondering how the ActiveCell.Offset(column,row).Range().Select line worked. In this case the "Start" range is a cell, A18, and the offset offsets it by one row, that much I get. But I'm not following how or what the Range("A1") is being inserted to do here.

Wouldn't

```
Sheets("Setup").Select
Range("Start").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

work just the same and be less confusing? Is there any reason the Range("A1") clause is inserted?

Thanks so much, and sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: Yes, it would work the same and be less confusing. :)

Comment: Thanks Rory! Any thoughts on the Range("A1") part then and why it still performs the same function?

Comment: See the answer from @chancea for how it works. As for the why: it's put there by the macro recorder if you have the 'use relative references' option checked when recording a macro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short answer

Yes *in this particular case* both do the same.  Removing `Range("A1")` is fine.

#### Long Answer

This is due to the fact you are using `ActiveCell` in this line:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

The `ActiveCell` is the first cell *within the range* you have selected.

Consider the following macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Whatever range you select this will print the address of the *white cell* within the selection.

i.e.

[image]

The `ActiveCell` is `$A$4`

#### Example

Calling `Offset(1,0)` on a *single cell* will only offset *that cell*.  So if we look at your original code:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Setup").Select
    Range("Start").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Let us assume that my previous selection shown (`A2:B4`) is the named range of "Start" and we can walk through exactly what is happening:

1. In this example `Range("Start").Select` would select range `A2:B4`.  Thus making `ActiveCell` equal to `A2`.
2. Next we call `Offset(1,0)` on `ActiveCell` which is equivalent to `Range("A2").Offset(1,0)` putting us at range `A3` (1 row below A2)
3. Now we call `.Range("A1")` which is going to grab the *first cell* within the range.  Since the current range is **only** `A3`, `.Range("A1")` gives us `A3`.
4. Then of course `.Select()` is still only selecting `A3`

#### When is `.Range("A1")` actually useful?

Consider the following example without any `Range("A1")` call:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Sheets("Setup").Select
    Range("Start").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Since we have changed `ActiveCell` to `Selection` the `Offset(1,0)` will select the same dimension range as "Start" just offset-ed by 1 row.

i.e.:

If this is the range of "Start":

[image]

We run the example macro:

[image]

We have a new selection of the same dimension.

However if we change the example macro to include the `Range("A1")`:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Sheets("Setup").Select
    Range("Start").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Only the *first* cell in the selection is now selected.

Comment: Of course, `Resize()` would achieve the same thing and be clearer, IMO. ;)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for taking the time. So I think I understand your explanation regarding the 'ActiveCell' as opposed to using a range ('Selection()'): we would move a single cell as opposed to a whole range by one row in the two separate scenarios. What I don't fully understand is why including the Range("A1") in the line of code doesn't alter the outcome of the line. Or moreover what exactly it's telling the Offset function to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @mburke05 I tried to update and clarify.  See my edit

Comment: @chancea so the `Offset(x,x).Range()` portion is just a definition for the size of whatever array it is you're going to be fooling around with, not an actual reference to the spot you'll be selecting? sorry i think you did a really good job explaining i'm just having trouble understanding exactly what `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select` vs `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` are defining. In python we see `open("file.txt", 'a')` the `a` is the addend optional definition of the open() function. In VBA is `<<Array>>.Offset().xxx.Select`, xxx is where he input the `Range()` and confused me.

Comment: @mburke05 if you think of a `Range` like a 2D-Array then basically calling `.Range(...)` on an existing range is like 'narrowing' the 2D-Array.  Think of "A1" as like position `(0,0)`.  So lets say `a =[[1,2],[3,4]]` if we say `a[0][0]` we get `1`.  In your example though, it is morel like `a =[[1]]` (a 2D-Array that contains only 1 item) so calling `a[0][0]` in that case would of course result in just `1`

Comment: To transfer that into excel lets say you have `Range("A2:B4")` selected.  so that in a 2D-Array format would look like `[[A2,B2],[A3,B3],[A4,B4]]` So lets say we call `Range("A2:B4").Range("A1:B1")` that _narrows the original array_ to the _first row_ and _first 2 columns_ so `Range("A2:B4").Range("A1:B1") = [[A2,B2]]`

Comment: perfect, that's what i had suspected (that utilizing the range("A1") basically relocated our select to the "A1" within our newly defined array (be it Selection() or ActiveCell().) awesome explanation, and thanks so much again.